# HTML input into Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I've been attempting to grab text input from HTML and trying to output the text back into HTML but for some reason it does not seem to be working. Does putting input within a form alter the interaction with getElementById or is it possible that the second button usage of formaction is interrupting this?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit").on("click",function(){
        var test = document.getElementById("searchInput");
        $("#text").html(test);
      })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
          <input type ="text" id ="searchInput"><br>
          <button id = "submit">Search</button>
          <button formaction="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" formtarget="_Blank">Random</button>
      </form>
    
      <div id = "text">
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
```

EDIT: I have attempted to change

```
var test = document.getElementById("searchInput");
```

to

```
var test = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
```

previously and it is still not working. Is there an interaction that is failing that I am missing? Also I would like to be able to store the input as variable i.e thats why I am purposely putting it into a variable before outputting it.

EDIT2: There wasn't anything particularly wrong about the code other than retrieving the value. I am currently using codepen.io to code and did not load jquery into the pen.

Comment: `document.getElementById("searchInput");` this gets the `<element>` and not the value, make sure this is what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, it will make more sense to use jQuery to obtain the elements' value:

Use this to always replace `#text` element contents with `#searchInput` value:

```php
$("#text").html($("#searchInput").val());
```

Use this to append #searchInput value to #text element:

```php
$("#text").append($("#searchInput").val());
```

But the whole logic does not make any sense. You are changing an elements' value that it is outside the form you are submitting. Either you should prevent submit button click event from submitting the form, or have the `#text` element inside the form as an `input`, `textarea` or `hidden` field:

```php
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#text").html($("#searchInput").val());
  })
});
```

or having the `#text` element inside the form for submitting:

```php
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="text" name="text">
    <input type ="text" id ="searchInput"><br>
    <button id = "submit">Search</button>
    <button formaction="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" formtarget="_Blank">Random</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not attempting to change part of form, I am attempting to get whatever the string input is into a variable within JS when i click the submit button.

Comment: When you hit the submit button, the browser will submit the form and the page will be refreshed with the submitted data. The `#text` field is outside the form, so it won't be passed to the `POST`/`GET` data to display or use. You should either move the `#text` element inside the form so the data will be passed to the refreshed page, or cancel the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

You Using form element, so once you click the button , the form will be reloaded, if you want to display textbox value to the element , once remove the form element.

```
     <input type ="text" id ="searchInput"><br>
      <button id = "submit">Search</button>
      <button formaction="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" formtarget="_Blank">Random</button>


  <div id ="text">
    <h1 id="welc"></h1>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").on("click",function(){     
    var test = $('#searchInput').val();  
    $("h1").html(test);
  });
});
  </script>
```

Just Remove  tag, and check it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to find the element's value and then set it as HTML.

```
$("#text").html(test.value);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have updated your question mate check this one .

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit").on("click",function(){
        var test = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
        $("#text").html(test);
      })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
          <input type ="text" id ="searchInput"><br>
          <button id = "submit">Search</button>
          <button formaction="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" formtarget="_Blank">Random</button>
      </form>
    
      <div id = "text">
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work for you.

```html
<! doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="searchInput">
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="submit">Search</button>
        <button formaction="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" formtarget="_Blank">Random</button>
    </form>

    <div id="text">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").on("click", function () {
            $("#text").html($("#searchInput").val());
        })
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: i would say the downvote is becouse no explanation why this code should work. Dont know exactly sometimes there are downvoters just becouse they can.

Comment: This is not a complex code at all. Anyone can look into it and its self explanatory. If any explanations are required you can just put in the comment. Its not a big deal to add a 2 line explanation for a 20 line code. Also we are willing to give explanations if needed.

Answer (score -2):

Edit your JS code please try:
EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").on("click",function(){
    var test = $("#searchInput").val();
    $("#text").html(test);
  })
});
```